# Angular global variable sometimes undefined

Tags: angular, typescript, components

I have a component which takes in an @Input variable that it uses to construct a local string. This takes place in ngOnChanges. My HTML then contains an *ngIf looking for this local variable. My Problem/Question is after verifying the variable has been set, my *ngIf wasn't displaying. I threw in a console log into my ngAfterViewChecked with the local variable and it shows my variable toggling between unidentified and what it was set too. In the end my element is not showing after I've verified the varible has been set. What am I missing here?

.ts

```
@Input() type: string;

title: string;

constructor() { }

ngOnChanges() {
    console.log('into ngOnChanges');       

    if (this.type) {
        console.log('this.type is', this.type);
        this.title = this.type + ' is the type';
        console.log('title is', this.title);
    }
}

ngAfterViewChecked() {
    console.log('afterViewChecked title is', this.title);
}
```

.HTML

```
<span *ngIf="title" class="uppercase">{{title}}</span>
```

console.logs are

```
into ngOnChanges
this.type is something
title is something is the type
afterViewChecked title is undefined
afterViewChecked title is something is the type
afterViewChecked title is undefined
```

In addition, I placed a button with a click event to a method logging the variable. The log spits out that title is undefined however the following afterViewChecked logs repeat the above....'undefined'...'something is the type'...'undefined'.

.ts

```
whatIsTitle() {
    console.log('what is title...', this.title);
}
```

.HMTL (button)

```
<button (click)="whatIsTitle()" class="btn btn-sm btn-default">Title?</button>
```

console.log

```
what is title... undefined
afterViewChecked title is undefined
afterViewChecked title is something is the type
afterViewChecked title is undefined
```

**UPDATE**
Here's a link to a stackblitz i mocked up to explain a little futher.
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-yyttwp

This works and shows no signs of the problem I'm having. So now I'm looking into other environment variables with my project as my above code appears to clearly be working(at least according to stackblitz)

**UPDATE 2**
I'm not getting anywhere with the environment variables yet however I just wanted to update something I discovered. It appears that the problem isn't exclusive to the couple variables. If I place a log of 'this' next to the title log from earlier in the ngAfterViewChecked, I can see that the everything in the entire component reverts back to undefined.

.ts

```
console.log('this is...', this);
```

console log in browser

```
afterViewChecked title is undefined
afterViewChecked this is... >Component {} 
afterViewChecked title is something is the type
afterViewChecked this is... >Component {type: "something", title: "something is the type" } 
afterViewChecked title is undefined
afterViewChecked this is... >Component {}
```

Comment: Can you make a plunker or a stackblitz showing the problem?

Answer (score -1):

It is because your title and type are undefined. I have manually tried to initialize these variables but you can initialize them according to your requirements.

```
import {Input, OnChanges, SimpleChanges} from '@angular/core'

export class App implements OnChanges{
@Input() type ='hi';

title: string = 'hi';
constructor() { }

ngOnChanges(changes: SimpleChanges) {
console.log('into ngOnChanges');       

if (this.type) {
    console.log('this.type is', this.type);
    this.title = this.type + ' is the type';
    console.log('title is', this.title);
}
}
whatIsTitle() {
console.log('what is title...', this.title);
}

ngAfterViewChecked() {
console.log('afterViewChecked title is', this.title);
}
}
```

[Plunker demo](https://plnkr.co/edit/H0KX1KKpymBblM3ml6d9?p=preview)

Also, take a look at the [UpgradeComponent](https://angular.io/api/upgrade/static/UpgradeComponent#ngOnChanges) class for more in depth reference

Comment: Sorry, i wasn't clear. The component is only visible after the input has been passed in. Here's a link to a demo stackblitz i mocked up. https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-yyttwp